# About the Cartesian Form of Bounded Operators

Tags: functional-analysis

We know that any $T\in B(H)$ may be expressed as $T=A+iB$ where $A$ and $B$ are self-adjoint. Also $T$ is normal iff $AB=BA$. There is surely something wrong about the following:

Let $T=A+iB$ be any boudned operator. Then $T^*=A-iB$. Hence
\begin{equation}
TT^*=A^2+B^2+i(BA-AB).
\end{equation}

However, $TT^*$ is always positive (in particular self-adjoint) and so necessarily $BA=AB$. This makes the arbitrary $T$ normal!!!

Any help or hint is welcome.

Math

Comment: Have you seen my question?

Comment: Why does $-i((BA-AB)x,x) \le (A^2x,x)+(B^2x,x)$ imply that $AB=BA$? Also note that $i(BA-AB)$ is selfadjoint.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there had better be a problem here. There's a step I didn't see how to verify: Why does $A^2+B^2+i(BA-AB)\ge0$ imply $BA-AB=0$? That looks right, by analogy with complex numbers, but in fact it's wrong.

Work everything out with $T=\begin{bmatrix}2&2\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$ and you see that $A^2+B^2+i(BA-AB)$ manages to be positive even though $BA-AB\ne0$.

So the actual error is you never actually proved that step was correct, you just accepted it because it looked right.

I just realized something here, let's call it Dave's Principle:

> > **Moral:** Various analogies between operators and complex numbers are great for normal operators, that being sort of the point to the Spectral Theorem, but can lead you astray when applied to non-normal operators.

Of course there's another less specific moral:

> > Look at an *example*!

Comment: Very many thanks indeed.

Comment: @Math If you believe it's right you're supposed to at least "accept" it by clicking on the little checkmark...